# sort and count occurences of 12 giga text file

Tags: python-2.7

I want to sort a big text file (about 12 Giga), by counting the occurrences of each line. For that I have used :

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c > sorted
```

But it is taking forever because of  geometrical expansion. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it takes "forever" because you don't have enough RAM? Splitting the file into chunks could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

with open(file.txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        d[line]+=1
```

d now contains a dictionary, where each key is a unique line, and the value is the count of that line.

Comment: You could use `collections.Counter` for even more simple operation: `with open("file.txt") as f: d = collections.Counter(f)`

Comment: titan - out of curiosity, how long does it take to run my code on your 12GB file?

Comment: @titan you are very welcome, but could you possibly tell me how long it did take to run, how much faster was it? how long was it before? i am just curious. good luck.

Comment: it took me : The time is 480.929841995seconds

Comment: it was taking forever with the sort function, more than 2 weeks, and in a cluster HPC